# Python save binary image: PNG file corrupted by ASCII conversion

Tags: python, image, encoding, request, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use python to save image files I get by request urls. Here is the code for get content and saving.

```
response = requests.request(method='get',
                                        url=adsRequestUrl[idx], headers={'Connection': 'close'})
content = response.content
```

Tried two ways to save the image

```
im = Image.open(BytesIO(content))
im.save('./ads_response/' + today + '/' + str(ad_requests_db_id[idx]) + 'picture' + today + '.png')
```

The other one I tried

```
with open('./ads_response/' + today + '/' + str(ad_requests_db_id[idx]) + 'picture' + today + '.png', 'wb',  100000000) as file:
     file.write(content)
```

[image: request pic]
[image: save pic]
When I print the content of response in the code, it shows like this.

```
b'GIF89a\x01\x00\x01\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff!\xf9\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\x01D\x00;'
```

[image: content pic]
But after it saved in my device( I tried both centos and windows), it has error to open and read. When I open the file in text editor, it shows like this, which is not like the content I printed out.

```
‰PNG
V¶¨P†z0áÛíëhú<€A
```

When I tried to open it in image. It said either don't support this file format or fatal error reading PNG image file: PNG file corrupted by ASCII conversion.
Could someone help me find out the problem and fix it? I really don't understand it.

[image: windows pic]
[image: windows pic]
[image: centos pic]
[image: centos pic]

Comment: [Please do not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70016297/edit) link to modify your question.  That said, PNG files are binary and shouldn't be decoded, but you haven't shown any code that caused this error.

Comment: Based on the hostnames etc. visible in the screenshots, you seem to be running the code on a remote machine, and then transferring the file over to your machine. Is that correct? If so, are you sure the transfer process is treating binary files correctly?

Comment: Yes. I am downloading from a server by using winscp. Do you know how to check if it treat binary file correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Writing the content as a binary file should be all you need.  From the file content the file is a GIF not a PNG.  Here's a working example:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://media.giphy.com/media/7ay2nTElNYaEo/giphy.gif')
>>> r
<Response [200]>
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'image/gif'
>>> r.headers['content-length']
'611800'
>>> r.content[:40]
b'GIF89a@\x01\xf0\x00\xf6\x00\x00/0/\x17\x18\x16XXWGHG\x02\x02\x02<><MOM\x11\x12\x11$%$'
>>> with open('test.gif','wb') as f:
...   f.write(r.content)
...
611800
```

The resulting `test.gif` opened correctly and displayed the image.

Converting to a PNG works as well, but loses the animation supported by the GIF:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> r = requests.get('https://media.giphy.com/media/7ay2nTElNYaEo/giphy.gif')
>>> i=Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
>>> i
<PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile image mode=P size=320x240 at 0x24A33B45730>
>>> i.save('test.png')
```

The resulting `test.png` was a still image from the animated GIF.